# EXCEL 360 - Run Formula if a cells numeric value is above a nominated value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can't seem to figure out this simple formula.

I have a value in a particular cell based upon a previous calculation. If that value is above 120 then I need to multiply the value over 120 by 25 and place the result into another cell. I tried an IF function but that seems to be focussed on words or type.

So what I am trying to do is provide a result for cell D10 with the following calculation:

```
If C10>120 then (C10-120)*25
```

Let's say for argument sake that the value in C10 is 135, then the result that needs to be posted to D10 is 375 i.e 15 * 25, because I am only interested in the value above 120. However, if it is equal to or below 120, then the value in D10 needs to be 0 (zero).

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the formula below?

```
=IF(C10>120,(C10-120)*25,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, Emily. It looks like i had stupidly forgot the brackets around the second part of the equation. It worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
=MAX(A1-120,0)*25
```

[image]